# Angular 2: Parent-Child Component Property Binding

Tags: angular, boolean, parent-child, angular-components, property-binding

How do you property bind a child component? I want to make my variable `high` to `false or !this.high` through its parent component but the thing is, the child is being looped

**app-product**

```
<button class="ui primary small button"(click)="clearVals()">Clear Selected</button>
<app-product-list [dataSource]="data"></app-product-list>


@ViewChild(ProductListComponent) prodList: ProductListComponent;
clearVals() {
    this.selectedOutsourced = this.selectedPrice = 0;
    this.prodList.clear();
    this.selectedArray = [];
}
```

**app-product-list**

```
<div class="products-cards" *ngFor="let product of dataSource['docs']">
      <app-product-card [product]="product"(highlightEvent)="highlight($event)">
      </app-product-card>
</div>


@ViewChild(ProductCardComponent) prodCard: ProductCardComponent;
```

**app-product-card**

```
<div class="list card ui" (click)="highlight()" [class.selected]="high"> </div>


high : boolean = false;
highlight(){
     this.high = !this.high;
}
```

That is the order of the parenting. The topmost is the parent down to its child

Comment: What does 'the child is being looped' even mean?

Comment: are you trying to propagate event from child to parent ?

Comment: *ngFor @Carsten

Comment: @RahulSingh there's still actually another parent wherein, if you click that button, it would viewchild the **app-product-list** component

Comment: its confusing @Char

Comment: I will try to update my question @RahulSingh

Comment: @Char Wait you try to highlight on hover or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is funny I just noticed after reading this like 5 thimes.

Your div has a *ngFor.
Your child is in that div, So the child will be looped ofc.

```
<div class="products-cards" *ngFor="let product of dataSource['docs']">
          <app-product-card [product]="product"(highlightEvent)="highlight($event)">
          </app-product-card>
    </div>
```

Should be

```
    <div class="products-cards" *ngFor="let product of dataSource['docs']">
        </div>
<app-product-card [product]="product"(highlightEvent)="highlight($event)">
              </app-product-card>
```

Then in your child

```
@Input()
  set product(product: any) {
    highlightF(product);
  }

highlightf(product: any){
  this.hightlight.emit(product);
}
```

Now in your parent:

```
//Do something to set product.highlight
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the code in child component as

**app-product-card child component** typescript

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Input() product: any;

@Output() highlightEvent= new EventEmitter();

highlight(){
   this.highlightEvent.emit(somevalue);

}
```